# Use of INDIRECT reference within an IF Function statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook with a summary sheet and several tabs for various products. The source tab sheets have the data of products sold by each day of the month with a different tab for each product.  The summary sheet currently uses IF statements to pull the quantity sold based on the day of the month.  For example if it is day 4 it will pull the sales for that particular day.  Here is a snippet of the formula

```
IF($D$1=4,'CM1'!$F3,IF($D$1=3,'CM1'!$E3,IF($D$1=2,'CM1'!$D3,IF($D$1=1,'CM1'!$C3))))
```

The D cell reference is to the day number and the 'CM1'!$F3 is to a specific tab and cell on that tab. The tab reference is currently hardcoded as CM1 or CM2 or CM3, etc.

What I want to do is create a dropdown list on the summary sheet with the various tabs which could be selected and have that value replace the CM1 (or CM2, CM3, etc) in the hardcoded formula above.  All other cell references would remain the same.  The actual formulas are very long so I would like to utilize a find and replace once the correct INDIRECT reference is built.

Answer (score 1):

Build a cell address for INDIRECT with the ADDRESS function.

```
'This:
IF($D$1=4,'CM1'!$F3,IF($D$1=3,'CM1'!$E3,IF($D$1=2,'CM1'!$D3,IF($D$1=1,'CM1'!$C3))))
'could be written as,
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(3:3), $D$1+2, 4, 1, "CM1"))
```

If your drop-down with worksheet names is in C1 then this becomes,

```
INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(3:3), $D$1+2, 4, 1, $C$1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDIRECT("'"& CELL WITH DROP DOWN HERE &"''!$F3")
```

If you drop down cell had CM2 in it then the above would evaluate to ='CM2'!$F3. So if D1 was where you wanted the drop down then you would use:

```
=INDIRECT("'"& D1 &"''!$F3")
```

This can then be combined with any number of nested IF statements.

If Row 3 needs to be dynamic and dragged down then you can use (inspired by Jeeped Answer) :

```
=INDIRECT("'"& D1 &"''!$F"&ROW(3:3))
```